# How can I make a fieldset-like component using div and label components?

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems using a table with a horizontal scroll within a fieldset, exceeding the lateral limits of the page.
I looked for some alternatives, but without success.
Inside the div the table is not exceeding the limits, it is correct.
Now I need to know how to put a label in a position similar to the legend of the fieldset.

CSS for both examples:

```css
fieldset {
    width: 500px;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

th, td { 
    min-width: 300px; 
}

div {
    width: 500px;
    overflow-x: scroll; 
    padding: 20px; 
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

In this example the horizontal bar is added in the browser and not in the table:

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    Legend Fieldset
  </legend>
  <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

In this example it is correct, but the legend (label) is not positioned correctly, to look like the fieldset legend.

```html
<label>Legend Fieldset</label>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```css
th, td { 
    min-width: 300px; 
}

.div {
    width: 500px;
    overflow-x: scroll; 
    padding: 20px; 
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

label{
  position: relative;
  top: 10px; /* change this how you need */
  left: 20px;/* change this how you need */
  background-color:white;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Legend Fieldset</label>
  <div class="div">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>      
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
 </div>
```